# Removing data points from StockChart in HighChart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The following api is used to remove data points from a simple HighChart

> series[i].data[j].remove(false, false)

When I am trying to use the same api for StockChart, it doesn't work and 
`series[i].data.length = 0` always but `series[i].yDdata.length` has some value and graph is also plotted correctly

Comment: wouldn't yData be updated when you redraw the chart?

Comment: `yData` is getting updated but `data` length is 0. Everything is fine on chart display. Even I am not able to replicate this issue with other charts. Any idea why this is happening.

Comment: Do you have live example of this issue? Like jsFiddle?

Comment: Additionally, maybe you can use points array instead of data array?

Comment: `data` length becomes 0 when you remove just one point from the array?